# Change numbering language of the Excel context by changing the Windows language

Tags: microsoft-excel

How could we **change the numbering language** of MS **Excel 2010** by changing Windows language

*In version 2007* as I can remember we had an option in the advanced options tab that allowed us
to do that with setting it as **"Context"** ,

so it smartly change the numbering system whenever we change the language of Windows .

Comment: Have you tried looking under Options->Language->Choose editing languages?

Answer (score 2):

`file - options - language` and under `choose editing languages` `add` the language you'd like to use. Once it's added, `set as default`

Answer (score 2):

1. Select the area of the cells that you need to change
2. Press Ctrl+1 using keybard
3. Go to Customes and type this code: [$-2000000]#,##0.00
4. This will give you comma seperate and 2 decimals

Comment: This seems to be pretty much the same as [Mohammad Siddiqui’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/266070/150988#1153140), except you have added a decimal point and two decimal digits. Can you explain how this format works?  What does the number between the brackets mean?  Can you provide a reference that documents these codes? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert numeric numbers to Arabic numbers:

1. Select the area of cells that you want to change
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> for Format Cell
3. Go to Custom and type this code: `[$-2060000]0`

Comment: (1) I believe that this does not answer the question that is being asked. It asks how to change the numbering language of MS Excel ***by changing the Windows language**.* You have described how to do it within Excel. (2) This information is probably useful to somebody. Can you explain how this format works? What does the number between the brackets mean? (It seems to me that you could use any number between 2 000 000 and 2 999 999 and get the same results. Am I wrong?) Can you provide a reference that documents these codes? … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.