# Change language of Excel numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, language

My Excel tabs and commands are in English, yet the numbers are shown in German (0,1 instead of 0.1). I looked here ([Change numbering language of the Excel context by changing the Windows language](https://superuser.com/questions/266070/change-numbering-language-of-the-excel-context-by-changing-the-windows-language?newreg=eb281f232810474ca0ae93a8fffd8cbf)) but it doesn't resolve it. How can I switch to English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number notation settings use the system locale setting.

In order to set this to english, go to *Control Panel* > *Country / Region* and find the <kbd>More settings...</kbd> at the bottom.

There you can change the notation settings. This will change the settings for the entire system though, and there's no way around it.

Answer (score 10):

**1st (only changes in Excel)**

- In Excel go to **File** - **Options** - **Advanced**
- Under **Editing Options** uncheck **Use system separators** and set your own.

---

**2nd Option**

- From **Start** button search for **Region** settings.
- In the new window, under **Formats** tab change to English then press OK.